# Formal Verification for Multiparty Computation and Homomorphic Encryption?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, provable-security, multiparty-computation, universal-composability

I've recently found some work on the use of Formal Verification Software, like ProVerif for enclaves. I wonder is if its feasible to  have something similar for MPC and Homomorphic Encryption and their applications?

I always thought there were limitations adopting simulation based proofs and Universal Composability, in general, in Formal Verification, but as of late I'm thinking there must be more powerful reasons.

Comment: I think there are many aspects to your question. I will only comment on MPC. The proofs are often written in the UC framework because it allows arbitrary composition. As far as I know, formal verification tools do not support this.

Comment: Ok, now imagine if we work in the context of Secure Function Evaluation, would that make things easier with respect of Formal Verification?

Comment: "How to Simulate It in Isabelle: Towards Formal Proof for Secure Multi-Party Computation",  1805.12482 on arxiv

Comment: Hi.. so there is some work from people like Maurer: "Abstract Modeling of System Communication in Constructive Cryptography using CryptHOL" but if you see the kind of venues they appear.. I wonder what are the main motivations not to embrace formal verification

Comment: If you guys notice.. these works are quite adamant on what they could do... like improving simulation for secure channels.. not what cannot be done.. so that is still my question.. what is really blocking the use of Formal Verification?

Comment: I stand corrected, there are tools that allows formal verification of UC-based proofs https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/582.pdf. I imagine there's nothing that's fundamentally stopping you from using formal verification for MPC, it's just there's not enough people and not enough time to do this kind of work.